# How can I make a type="submit" look in css like a type="button"

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

Im trying to make a website that takes and stores info on people or things. When someone type in a username and click the button is clicked it finds the directory labeled what the user imputed. If there is no file it goes to an error page.

The problem i'm having is `<input type="button" name="search" value="Search Database">` is how i want it to look but it only submits if i change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` and this changes the css so it looks funny.

Please help me fix the button problem Thanks, I really appreciate it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <title>Genetics Database</title>

    <style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:100,200,400);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:700,400,300);

body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #fff;

 color: #fff;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.body{
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 left: -20px;
 right: -40px;
 bottom: -40px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background-image: url(http://ginva.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/city-skyline-wallpapers-008.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 z-index: 0;
}

.grad{
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 left: -20px;
 right: -40px;
 bottom: -40px;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0.7;
}

.header{
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(50% - 40px);
 left: calc(50% - 270px);
 z-index: 2;
}

.header div{
 float: left;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
 font-size: 35px;
 font-weight: 200;
}

.header div span{
 color: #5379fa !important;
}

.login{
 position: absolute;
 top: calc(50% - 75px);
 left: calc(50% - 50px);
 height: 150px;
 width: 350px;
 padding: 10px;
 z-index: 2;
}

.login input[type=text]{
 width: 250px;
 height: 30px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 4px;
}

.login input[type=password]{
 width: 250px;
 height: 30px;
 background: transparent;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 4px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=button]{
 width: 260px;
 height: 35px;
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-radius: 2px;
 color: #a18d6c;
 font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: 400;
 padding: 6px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.login input[type=button]:hover{
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.login input[type=button]:active{
 opacity: 0.6;
}

.login input[type=text]:focus{
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.login input[type=password]:focus{
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.login input[type=button]:focus{
 outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder{
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}

::-moz-input-placeholder{
   color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
</style>

    <script src="js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="grad"></div>
  <div class="header">
   <div>YouR<span>Genetics</span></div>
   <br>
   <div> Database</div>
  </div>
  <br>
 <form action="/database/search.php" method="post">
  <div class="login">
   <br><br>
   <input type="text" name="userinfo"  placeholder="Username/Keyword" ><br>
   <input type="button" name="search" value="Search Database">
  </div>

  <script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: when it comes to the CSS, why cant you change it to `input[type=submit]` rather than `input[type=button]` , are there any reasons?

Comment: you're missing the closing tag of your `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the closing tag of your `form`. Make sure you include that. And change your CSS `input['submit']` to this: `input[type=submit]`, now you can change your HTML button to type submit. It should work